# Pressure Cooker Problem

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, entropy

I am working on a thermodynamics problem involving a pressure cooker and have come across two different approaches to solve it. Surprisingly, both methods yield the same result. I am looking for some guidance and clarification on why this is the case, and if one of the methods is more appropriate than the other. Here's the problem:

> A pressure cooker has a volume of 6 L and an operating pressure of 75
> kPa (relative). Initially, the cooker contains 1 kg of liquid water.
> Heat is supplied at a rate of 500 W for 30 minutes after the operating
> pressure has been reached. Assuming the atmospheric pressure is 100
> kPa, determine the amount of water contained in the pressure cooker at
> the end of the process.

---

**Method 1:**

The energy change of the closed system (inside the cooker) is described as:

$$u_2 m_2 - u_1 m_1 = Q - m_\text{out} h_\text{out}$$

Where:

- $u_1, u_2$ are the specific internal energies at the initial and
  final states, respectively
- $m_1, m_2$ are the masses of water at the initial and final states,
  respectively
- $Q$ is the heat supplied to the system
- $m_\text{out}$ is the mass of the water that left the system
- $h_\text{out}$ is the specific enthalpy of the water that left the
  system

---

**Method 2:**

The energy change of the closed system can also be described as:

$$\Delta E = m_\text{out} \Delta h $$

Where:

- $m_\text{out}$ is the mass of the water
- $\Delta h$ is the change in specific enthalpy

Comparing both methods, I found that they yield the same result for the amount of water contained in the pressure cooker at the end of the process.

---

**Question:**

Why do these two different approaches lead to the same result in this case? Is one of them more appropriate or valid than the other? I am looking for an explanation and clarification on this matter.

Thank you in advance for your insights.

Comment: Because they are both expressions of the energy conservation, but in terms of different quantities?

Comment: Yes, I understand that but my question is: both expressions represent energy conservation but with different quantities. The internal energy variation (u_2 m_2 – u_1 m_1) equals the energy entering and leaving the system (Q - m_out h_out). The control volume is the pot, with work only in outflow (h_out). The H values in ΔU = H2 - H1 are not saturated, only h_out is. Further discussion requires demonstrating the equality between expressions, which I cannot prove.

Comment: Do the two equations give the exact same result? Let's see your own analysis of this problem.

Comment: @ChetMiller Yes. If you solve the problem using the first equation you get that m2 = 0.594 kg, with u2 = 505,2 kj/kg and x2 = 0,009024. By using the second equation you get that m2 = 0.594 kg.

Comment: Do you neglect the mass of the vapor in the pressure cooker?

Comment: @ChetMiller In some way I did. I calculated a formula that doesn't neglect the mass of vapor in the pressure cooker having in mind that the mass inside the cooker stays the same for the same pressure: 
\[m_{vapor2} = \frac{m_{content} - m_{content}}{\rho_{water} - \rho_{water\ vapor}} .\] 
But \[\frac{\rho_{water\ vapor}}{\rho_{water}} \ll 1,\] 
so I think we can neglect that.

Comment: I did this problem both ways and got the same answer analytically.

Comment: @ChetMiller Could yoy please help me prove that the expressions are equal? I'm left here: The variation of energy of the closed system (inside the pressure cooker - ΔE = u2m2 - u1m1) must be equal to the sum of the energy that enters and leaves the system (ΔE = Q - m_out h_out). That is, ΔE = u2m2 - u1m1 = Q - m_out h_out.

The control volume is the pressure cooker, and there is no work associated with pressure variations. The total volume of the water does not change, so there is no work in the evolution from state 1 to state 2. The only work is in the outflow, which is included in h_out.

Comment: Assuming that the pressure inside the pressure cooker remains constant, the process is isobaric. Furthermore, as the water reaches its boiling point at this constant pressure, it undergoes a phase change from liquid to vapor, and the temperature remains constant during this phase change. Therefore, the process is also isothermal.

Under isothermal conditions, the variation in temperature (ΔT) is equal to 0. Therefore, the variation in internal energy (ΔU) can be expressed as:

ΔU = cv * ΔT

Since ΔT = 0:

ΔU = cv * 0 = 0

Thus, the variation in internal energy (ΔU) is equal to 0.

Comment: Expressing the variation of the total internal energy of the system (Δ(mU)):
Δ(mU) = m2u2 - m1u1 = 0

Here, u1 and u2 are the specific internal energies of the water in the initial and final states, respectively.

Rewriting the first law equation of open systems in terms of the variation of the total internal energy of the system:

Q = (m2u2 - m1u1) + m_out h_out = m_out h_out (Method 1)

In Method 2:

ΔE = m_out Δh

Substituting the expression for Δh:

ΔE = m_out [(u2 + p2v2) - (u1 + p1v1)] = m_out h_out

But that means that h_out = h_fg and not h@sat, right?

Comment: They have closed this thread, so it is very difficult to help you at this site.  Please re-submit your question at PhysicsForums.com, and I will be pleased to help you work out all the details.  Let me start out by saying that the initial heating up  part of the operation is not included in this question.  In addition, since the proportions of liquid and vapor within the cooker change during the processing, dU is not just equal to CvdT.

Comment: @ChetMiller Thanks! I've posted my question here: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/pressure-cooker-problem.1051998/

Comment: Initial response posted.

Comment: @ChetMiller Thanks!